# Relationship between my paternal aunt and maternal uncle

Tags: kinship-terms

I have an aunt by marriage on my dad's side who is his sister-in-law and an uncle by blood on my mom's side who is her brother. Would my aunt and uncle be considered sister-in-law and brother-in-law to each other?

Comment: They are "cousins by marriage".

Comment: This example could be simplified by removing the generation gap: what is the relationship between my brother's wife and my wife's brother?

Comment: They are in no way related... However, if they married each other, your aunt would be sister-in-law to both your mother and father.

Comment: I cannot find it, hence the comment here, but the lyrics of *I am my own Grandpa* would explain the consequences of the elopement.

Answer (score 1):

I have a case like that in my family and what they are called is "husband and wife".

Yes, their spouses died at some point and they ended up marrying each other.

I've also got ancestors where it turned out that 3 bothers from one family married 3 sisters from another family.  I guess when you have to travel by horse or mule for 20 miles to find someone who does not have any blood relation to you, if you find 3 of them, you figure you've hit the jackpot.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zeIsxXDyjlc

Comment: @HotLicks -- Sometimes we don't have a family "tree", it's more of a low shrub or cluster of vines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the case correctly, it doesn't sound like they are brother-in-law and sister-in-law.

Your aunt married your father's brother; thus your aunt and father are brother- and sister- in law.

Your mother's brother (your uncle) is also called your father's brother-in-law.

So your aunt is your uncle's brother-in law's sister-in-law.

Comment: I'll bet there is a word for it in Chinese.

Comment: I suspect many, if not most families, would go with Hot Licks, or refer to them loosely as brother-and-sister-in-law 

I think strictly, they have no official relationship. 

Either way, don't the mother and her brother have exactly the same relationship to the dad and his wife, the only difference being everyone-s tie to the guy Asking?